# Banco de dados SQlite no projeto android

Tags: android, sqlite

Boa tarde, estou com uma dúvida, estou fazendo um projeto no Android Stúdio e meu aplicativo tem uma ideia de bloco de notas, e queria saber se tem como mostrar as anotações quando inicializar a página, exemplo: o usuário clica no "+" aí abre uma janela para escrever, quando clicar em salvar ele salva no banco, quando clico voltar para a página principal anotação que o usuário fez apareça sem clicar em nada como se carregasse o banco de dados automaticamente. Teria como, ainda não cheguei fazer o código, teria como vocês me ajudarem, com links ou por conhecimento de vocês mesmo....

Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Comece por ler o que a documentação do *android* tem sobre [SQlite](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, tudo que você precisa pode ser encontrada na [documentação oficial dos developers](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html?hl=pt-br).

Bons estudos ^^